# How do I fetch a data by its ID to show on my client side - react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, client, fetch-api

ON MY SERVER

```
/* GET event listing by ID */
router.get('/:keyInfo_id', async function (req, res, next) {
  let { keyInfo_id } = req.params;

  try {
    let result = await db(`SELECT activities.keyInfo_id, date, title, deadline, activities_id, activityName, description, price, location FROM activities INNER JOIN keyInfo ON keyInfo.keyInfo_id = activities.keyInfo_id WHERE keyInfo.keyInfo_id = ${keyInfo_id} `);

    let event = result.data;
    if (event.length !== 0) {
      res.send(event);
    } else {
      // event array is empty... no event found
      res.status(404).send({ error: 'Event not found' });
    }
  }catch (err) {
    res.status(500).send({error: err.message});
  }
});
```

ON MY CLIENT SIDE - REACT

```
function App() {
  let [allEvents, setAllEvents] = useState([]);

  // useEffect() will call getEvent() when App is mounted on the DOM
  useEffect(() => {
    getEvent();  
  }, []);
  // the empty [] means only call it once

  //Get all the events
  async function getEvent() {
    try {
      let response = await fetch('/event');
      if (response.ok) {
        let data = await response.json();
        setAllEvents(data);
      } else {
        console.log(`Server error: ${response.status}: ${response.statusText}`);
      }
    } catch(err) {
      console.log(`Network error: ${err.message}`);
    }
  }

  // Get all the events by ID
  async function getEvent(id) {
    try {
      let response = await fetch('/:keyInfo_id');
      if (response.ok || response === id ) {
        let data = await response.json();
        setAllEvents(data);
      } else {
        console.log(`Server error: ${response.status}: ${response.statusText}`);
      }
    } catch(err) {
      console.log(`Network error: ${err.message}`);
    }
  }
```

I'm trying to fetch a data for an event in my sql table. So, when I change my client URL http://localhost:3000/dashboard/ and add /:keyInfo_id i can see on my page only the data from the event i want to and not all of them.

At the moment if i do http://localhost:3000/dashboard/3 (3 is the id of the event generate on mysql) my page is blank and won't show anything. and I don't understand why

Answer (score 0):

getEvent function name is used twice. Also add a view to show the data from allEvents.

Try `console.log(allEvents);` to find whether the data is properly fetched.